# Applying ItemStyle or HeaderStyle in GridView Skin

Tags: asp.net

I would like to apply default column-based styles to my `GridView` controls using a skin or other function of ASP.NET themes (or really any other automated way).

Currently my GridView skin looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" GridLines="None">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewRowHeader" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="GridViewRowHeader" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowA" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowB" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And a typical GridView column definition looks like this:

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ExitTimestamp" HeaderText="Exit" SortExpression="ExitTimestamp">
            <ItemStyle CssClass="GridViewCell" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeader" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Visitor Name/Agency">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitorName") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitorAgency") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="GridViewCell" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeader" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

What I would like to get around is having to add the `<ItemStyle>` and `<HeaderStyle>` elements to every column definition in my `GridView` controls.  I have tried various ways in the skin file including adding a `<Columns>` container and `<ItemStyle>` element therein, but nothing seems to work.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I just wanted to add that I posted this question in hopes of finding a cool ASP.NET Themes hack.  However it looks like CSS will have to handle the job, as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice here may work for you http://forums.asp.net/t/1063057.aspx in short define and add a CssClass to your gridview then use plain old CSS stylesheet to target and decorate the control.

Comment: Hm, that's a good idea, and something similar had crossed my mind as a last resort.  The cited example helps.  I anticipate problems differentiating between data rows and header/footer rows, though.

Comment: I did have a very similar flea in my ear about that - I think I got round it with CSS friendly control adapters but that project had other requirements that warranted the effort.

Comment: Checkout this blog post seems to have solved it nicely from a quick scan read http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, here is how I ended up specifically solving the problem using CSS.

I assigned a CSS class to the `GridView` in my skin file like so:

`<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="GridView">`

The style selects `td` (item) and `th` (header) cells within the `GridView` and works just as well as applying a plain CSS class directly with `ItemStyle` and `HeaderStyle` in your Column definitions:

```
table.GridView tr td, table.GridView tr th
{
   /* style attributes here */
}
```

Comment: Note that `table.GridView tr td, th` treats the `td` and `th` differently.  The style attributes will apply to ALL `th` unless you use `table.GridView tr td, table.GridView tr th` instead.